# CPP - Unhandled exception std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, mysql, 4d

Dear StackOverflow'ers,

I've been getting into coding with C++ and I took a project where I read information out of a 4D SQL database into MySQL syntax .sql files which in turn get executed by an MySQL server.
I'm running into the following problem; if I run the CreateSQL function with one table and then exit the programme, it runs fine.

If I loop the CreateSQL function to create SQL from all tables, it fails with a std::bad_alloc error.

Since I'm pretty new with C++, I was hoping if some of the more experienced C++ programmers could point me in the direction where this error could occur.
My (unexperienced) guess would be incorrect freeing of variables or the timing of this, as follows:

```
SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt ) ;
SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hConn ) ;
SQLFreeHandle( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv ) ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The full source code is below:

[Source code](https://pastebin.com/FHnQA1T6)

EDIT: Following François' advice from the comments:

```
for( int i = 1 ; i <= numRows ; i++ )
{
// Datatypes
// SQLGetData

char buf[256];
SQLINTEGER numBytes ;
newFile << createInsert(table);
for( int j = 1 ;
  j <= numCols ;
  j++ )
{

  retCode = SQLGetData(

    hStmt,
    j,           // COLUMN NUMBER of the data to get
    SQL_C_CHAR,  // the data type that you expect to receive
    buf,         // the place to put the data that you expect to receive
    255,         // the size in bytes of buf (-1 for null terminator)
    &numBytes    // size in bytes of data returned

  ) ;

    if( CHECK( retCode, "SqlGetData", false ) )
    {
        retCode2 = SQLDescribeColA( hStmt, j, colName, 255, &colNameLen, &dataType, &columnSize, &numDecimalDigits, &allowsNullValues ) ;
        if( CHECK( retCode2, "SQLDescribeCol" ) )
        {
            //cout << dataType << endl;
            if(dataType != 91) {
                newFile << "'" << removeSlashes(removeSpecials(buf)) << "'";
            }
            else if (dataType == 91) {
                newFile << "date_format(str_to_date('" << fixDate(buf) << "', '%d-%m-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')";
            }
        }
    //Sleep(50);
    }
    if(j != numCols) {
        newFile << ",";
    }

}
newFile << ");\n";
cout << "Regel #" << i <<  " van tabel " << table << " is verwerkt." << endl;

retCode = SQLFetch( hStmt ) ;
if( !SQL_SUCCEEDED( retCode ) )
{
  cout << "Tabel "+table+" is verwerkt." << endl;
  printf( "Regel %d is de laatste regel.\n", i ) ;
}
}
```

Comment: [This `std::bad_alloc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) might help explain what it's about. You're correct that it has to do with dynamically allocated memory, but not *freeing* it.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply, I shall look into that!

Comment: Users are more likely to pay attention to your question if you provide a [MCVE]. Providing a link to your code (not supplying it directly in the question) and providing such a large amount of it will discourage most users from considering your question.

Comment: You never free `array` in any of your functions.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux for your constructive feedback, I will correct this.

GillBates, I am familiar with clearing arrays in PHP, however not with the exact workings of this in C++, I shall read into this, thank you for your advice!

Comment: Just keep using `std::string` like you're doing, no need for any `new` allocations, remove those.

Comment: @GillBates Thank you for your constructive replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::bad_alloc` is thrown by `new` when it fails to allocate memory, usually because of memory exhaustion which usually indicates a memory leak somewhere in your program.

Your functions `createInsert` and `createSelect` are both littered by dynamic allocation that you do not `delete` :

```
char * array = new char[array_size];
```

Instead of dynamically allocating like this, you should use `std::string` and `operator>>` to extract from an `ifstream` and steer away from any dynamic allocation, there is always a better approach than manual allocation.

---

Side note, [`while(!file.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) is always bad.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the `while(!file.eof())`, I was not aware of this. And generally, thank you for your great help!